# SQL Query for duplicate records, retaining a list of the duplicate id's

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I want to collapse duplicate rows while also retaining a list of user_id containing those duplicates:

```
user_id  message                lattitude   longitude   status  img_name 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       hello test multiple     42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5m
4       hello test multiple     42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5m
5       hello test multiple     42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5m
6       hello test new          42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5WEXm
7       hello test new          42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5WEXm
8       hello test new          42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5WEXm
```

I want to collapse rows 3,4,5 and 6,7,8 into this:

```
user_id      message                lattitude   longitude   status  img_name 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3,4,5       hello test multiple     42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5m
6,7,8       hello test new          42.0473347  89.4525034  P       ced5WEXm
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: use group_concat for user_id field and group by message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`user_id` separator ',') as user_ids, 
       message,
       lattitude, 
       longitude, 
       status, 
       img_name    
   FROM table_name 
   GROUP BY img_name, message;
```

Use the Above query for the relevant result.

Comment: Select GROUP_CONCAT(`user_id` separator ',') as user_ids, GROUP_CONCAT( select username from tbUser where a.user_id= id) as username,
       message,
       lattitude, 
       longitude, 
       `job_status`, 
       img_name    
   FROM  tbjobLocation as a
   GROUP BY img_name


i am trying to get user name from tbuser but showing error hope you have the soluion

Comment: @AmitSharma use this query: `Select GROUP_CONCAT(a.user_id separator ',') as user_ids, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(b.username separator ',') as username,  
   a.message, a.lattitude, a.longitude, a.job_status, a.img_name 
   FROM tbjobLocation as a 
   LEFT JOIN tbUser ON a.user_id = b.id
   GROUP BY a.img_name`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id separator ','),
  message,
  lattitude,
  longitude,
  STATUS,
  img_name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY message,
  lattitude,
  longitude,
  STATUS,
  img_name
```

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cce60a/2)</kbd>

You may be able to remove some of the GROUP BY columns. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) to evaluate if any of those are in the conditions that mysql allows you to remove them for better performance on the query.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to adjust the group by columns:

```
select group_concat(user_id),
message,
lattitude,
longitude,
status,
img_name
from test
group by
message, img_name;
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b9b2/1